# Update environment variable that only shows up in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, zsh

I have an environment variable that is hidden somewhere associated with my Jupyter Notebook that I can't find. It's set to an old value and I would like to update it. But I don't see it in a terminal: when I run `env | grep MY_ENV_VAR`, it returns `MY_ENV_VAR=new_value`, as expected. But in a Jupyter Notebook, when I run `!echo $MY_ENV_VAR` or `import os;  print(os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR'])`, it prints `old_value`. I've tried looking everywhere I could think of - `.zshrc`, `/Users/me/.oh-my-zsh/custom/profile.zsh`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile` (even though I'm using zsh), `.bashrc`,  etc., as well as poking around in `/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs`, but I can't find where it's set to the old value anywhere. I've restarted the computer as well. The only way around I've found is to change it at the beginning of every Jupyter Notebook, but I'd rather fix the issue. How can I find where the old value is being set?

EDIT:

In case it's relevant, I'm also seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually had nothing to do with hidden environment variables. When I started jupyter it was looking for a kernel associated with an environment that no longer existed, so it got into a bad state. Once I cleaned that out the problem immediately went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was using Jupyter-Notebook installed through Anaconda. Whenever I set environment variable in my local laptop, it was not accessible in Jupter-notebook. Following below steps solved the issue:

1. Set environment variable in laptop/Desktop. In my case i am using Mac laptop

> vi ~/.zprofile

> export ENV_VAR = ***** (Your env value)

2. Now we need to update the same in Anaconda environment variables by using below command in terminal:

> conda env config vars set ENV_VAR = ****

and then activate the conda environment using

> conda activate required_environment